# How do I combine three text column in pandas using if & else

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 3.7
I have a pandas data frame with three text columns,name,email & section. The sample data looks like

```
Name   Email              Section
abc    abc@gmail.com      purchase
cde      -                drawing
lmn-pqr      None               -
```

Hyphen are there in between two words in all of the three columns. I would like to join three columns with "_" as separator  and create a new column group ignoring None or -.
My combined outcome will look like

```
Name   Email              Section   Group
abc    abc@gmail.com      purchase  abc_abc@gmail.com_purchase
cde      -                drawing   cde_drawing
lmn-pqr      None               -   lmn-pqr
```

I'm not sure about the python code. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) that gets rid of null values:

```
df.mask(df.isin(['-', None])).apply(lambda r: r.str.cat(sep='_'), axis=1)
```

or, manually:

```
df['Group'] = df.apply(lambda r: '_'.join([x for x in r.replace('-', pd.NA).dropna()]),
                       axis=1)
```

output:

```
      Name          Email   Section                       Group
0      abc  abc@gmail.com  purchase  abc_abc@gmail.com_purchase
1      cde              -   drawing                 cde_drawing
2  lmn-pqr           None         -                     lmn-pqr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try replace `-` with `None` then filter it out when join

```py
df['Group'] = df.replace({'-': None}).apply(lambda row: '_'.join(filter(None, row)), axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

      Name          Email   Section                       Group
0      abc  abc@gmail.com  purchase  abc_abc@gmail.com_purchase
1      cde              -   drawing                 cde_drawing
2  lmn-pqr           None         -                     lmn-pqr
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Group'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join([x['Name'], x['Email'], x['Section']))
```

x is a Series.